# Disable Number / Special Character Key Shortcuts

Tags: keyboard, mac, imac

This is driving me nuts.

I pressed something wrong, and suddenly my keyboard is doing shortcuts I don't want. The numbers / special characters above the letters are doing Function shortcuts. For example, my 1 and 2 keys are doing brightness down and up.

Keyboard is model A1243 wired to a 2013 iMac w/ OS Catalina.

It happened after I wiped my keyboard, pressing a bunch of keys randomly. I've tried to turn of num lock, change shortcuts, literally nothing is working.

I can't even use "shift" + 9 to do a parenthesis. When I do it types "5"

Unplugging and plugging back in did not affect the problem.

Please help.

Comment: That's unusual. Can you pls provide more details such as: What's your Mac model? Have you tried anything to fix this before writing this post? Are you using an external keyboard? Do you have any special software such as Karabiner or Ukulele installed?

Comment: No I don't. It's a model A1243. Another change is when I press "shift" and number 9 for a parenthesis, it types 6...

Comment: @user487481 - That’s a wired USB keyboard.  First, try unplugging it and then plugging it back in.  Next, reboot.  Third, try a different keyboard.  Let us know what the results are with an [edit] to the question.

Comment: I'll try to unplug. It's wired to a 2013 iMac with Catalina. But def not a software thing... it's 100 percent from me pressing keys and enabling some wacky shortcut stuff

Comment: It sounds broken to me.  Try another keyboard to verity.